# PHP code using preg_replace suddenly quit working last night

Tags: php

The following PHP code was working fine until last night:

```
// _camelize(sVal, bFirst)
private function _camelize($sVal, $bFirst = false) {
  $sVal = preg_replace("/([_-\s]?([a-z0-9]+))/e", "ucwords('\\2')", $sVal);
  return ($bFirst ? strtolower($sVal[0]) : strtoupper($sVal[0])) . substr($sVal, 1);
}
```

It no longer works and doing a var_dump on $sVal reveals that null was returned by the call to preg_replace().

I contacted Bluehost and they claim that nothing was done to the (shared) server during the night. I specifically asked if they changed the version of PHP. This was suspect because the documentation for preg_replace specifically mentions that the "\e" modifier is depreciated in PHP 5.5.0 and is removed completely in PHP 7.0.0. CPanel for this account currently indicates PHP 5.4.43 is being used.

I changed the code to the following:

```
// _camelize(sVal, bFirst)
private function _camelize($sVal, $bFirst = false) {
  $sVal = preg_replace_callback("/([_-\s]?([a-z0-9]+))/", 
    function($matches) {
      return ucwords($matches[2]);
    }, $sVal);

  return ($bFirst ? strtolower($sVal[0]) : strtoupper($sVal[0])) . substr($sVal, 1);
}
```

This worked on my test server (LAMP on local machine) but still didn't work on the production server.

To get the client's site back up quickly, I ended up ditching the preg_replace call completely and wrote some code which creates and iterates thorugh an array instead.

Can anyone explain what might have happened and why the second example (which uses preg_replace_callback) did not work? Could it have something to do with the Perl libraries?

Thanks for any help

BTW - The intent of this code is to take a string like "do-something-now" and return a string like "doSomethingNow".

Comment: I get _Warning:  preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 5_.  That indicates that the hyphen in the regex is being misinterpreted as a range.  It should be at the end. Instead of `[_-\s]?`, it probably needs to be expressed as `[_\s-]?`  Ensure you have error reporting turned all the way up and displaying when testing code.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: And indeed when I change that, the function converts `'this to camel case'` into `ThisToCamelCase`.  Are you certain this worked correctly before? I can't think of a situation where this regex would have ever compiled correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your host updated PHP to something before 5.4.41.
Your regular expression, `([_-\s]?([a-z0-9]+))`, only compiles on [version 5.4.40 and prior](http://3v4l.org/qtAln).

From the [patch notes](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) for 5.4.41, we see that the underlying PCRE library was updated:

> **PCRE:**
>   Upgraded pcrelib to 8.37. (CVE-2015-2325, CVE-2015-2326)

---

As for your `preg_replace_callback`, assuming you make the required character class change to `[_\s-]` it should have worked on [every version 5.3.0 onwards](http://3v4l.org/f7skv).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Making the suggested change worked perfectly and the additional patch notes were also very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is too complex for something so simple.

```
function camel_hump($words, $first=false){
    $words = str_replace(" ","",ucwords(strtolower(str_replace("-"," ", $words))));
    return $first ? $words : lcfirst($words);
}
echo camel_hump("these-are-some-words");
```

check it out here: http://3v4l.org/GNf2u

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question: `Can anyone explain what might have happened and why the second example (which uses preg_replace_callback) did not work? Could it have something to do with the Perl libraries?`

Comment: @Mr.Llama, you answered OP's question brilliantly, so I don't need ot. You didn;t offer a solution though. that's where i come in.

Comment: I agree, regex is too complicated for what was needed and I will look at using your solution instead. I already fixed the issue using another overly complicated solution but still needed an answer to the question so I could convince Bluehost tech support that something on the server changed.Thanks